# Wie drückt man das »Escapen« von Textlimitierungszeichen richtig auf Deutsch aus?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, technical-terminology

#### Beschreibung

In eigentlich allen Programmiersprachen kann man Zeichen, die den Start und das Ende einer Zeichenkette (String) beschreiben, durch ein sogenanntes *escape character* / Escape-Zeichen ungültig und somit als der Zeichenkette zugehörig markieren.

#### Beispiel

In PHP limitieren Anführungszeichen eine Zeichenkette. Möchte man Anführungszeichen innerhalb der Zeichenketten verwenden, so muss man ihnen ein `\` voranstellen.

```
$string = "Ich heiße \"Jonas\".";
```

So wird die Zeichenkette nicht als vorzeitig beendet erkannt und die den zweiten Anführungszeichen folgenden Zeichen erzeugen keine Fehler.

#### Frage

Mich interessiert nun, wie man das sogenannte Escapen von derartigen Zeichen richtig auf Deutsch formuliert. *Ausbrechen, austreten* oder *entfliehen* hören sich meiner Meinung nach nicht passend an.

Comment: [Relevantes XKCD](https://www.xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Du suchst das Wort *maskieren*.

> Die Anführungszeichen wurden mit einem rückwärtigen Schrägstrich **maskiert**.

Comment: Stimmt, danach gegoogelt kommt man schnell auf **Maskierungszeichen** oder **Fluchtsymbol**. Vielen Dank!

Comment: Rückschlag?????

Comment: *maskiert* kenne ich nicht in dieser Verwendung. *Fluchtsymbol* sehr wohl, auch wenn das nicht sehr gebräuchlich ist.

Comment: @CarstenS: ja. Wenn ich alte Computerbücher rauskrame, wurde der Backslash damals so genannt. Guidot hat es nun verschlimmbessert, denn *Rückwärtiger Schrägstrich* statt einfach *Rückwärtsschrägstrich* schreibt nun sonst wirklich niemand.

Comment: @tofro: das mag ja sein, dass du das nicht kennst, der OP kannte es auch nicht. Gebräuchlich ist das aber schon.

Comment: @user23885, wow das hatte ich noch nicht gehört. Wikipedia bietet noch Rückstrich an.

Comment: Das alles hat natürlich seine Daseinsberechtigung, wobei es mir eigentlich nur um das Wort für die Tätigkeit des Maskierens ging und nicht primär um den Namen des gespiegelten Schrägstrichs.

Comment: Die Frage und auch die Kommentare erinnern mich an meine Anfänge in der Computerei, was schon einige Jahre zurück liegt. MIr wäre neben `maskiert` noch `entwertet` eingefallen. Damals war es üblich dass (englische) Handbücher ins deutsche übersetzt wurden. und zwar mit allen Begriffen. Das Problem dabei: Man isoliert sich dabei sprachlich. Heutzutage sind die englischen Fachbegriffe eingedeutscht, was zwar manchmal seltsam klingt (`Die Datei kann man downloaden`, oder gar: `Ich habe die Datei downgeloadet` http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/downloaden), aber immerhin versteht es jeder.

Answer (score 2):

Ich tendiere auch primär zu **maskieren**, halte aber auch **schützen** für einen guten Begriff. Escapen selbst halte ich für eine denkbar schlechte Lösung, denn für Nichtinsider erschließt sich aus dem Wort gar nichts.